# error: nested name specifier for declaration does not refer into a class, class template or class template partial specialization

Tags: c++

Why error about "error: nested name specifier 'h::TYPE::' for declaration does not refer into a class, class template or class template partial specialization" show is only mark place?

```
#include <iostream>

namespace h
{
  enum TYPE 
  {
    A, B, C
  };

  struct test
  {
    test(TYPE type = B) { std::cout << type << std::endl; }
  };
};

int main() 
{
  h::test t{h::TYPE::A};
  h::test r(h::TYPE::A);
  h::test {h::TYPE::A};
  h::test (h::TYPE::A); <--- only here
}
```

[DEMO](https://godbolt.org/z/j9bb4ahhr)

Comment: I saw the code using my IDE, and found the problem. The variable definition is `h::test A` for some reason.

Comment: For me it feels that we see a compiler bug for clang here... gcc compiles fine and I can't see any problem with the code above. No idea why an anonymous instance should be handled differently as one with a name.

Comment: It could be useful to see how other compilers handles it, and also comment out the "comment" which otherwise will give lot of extra errors. E.g. [like this](https://godbolt.org/z/MPdPzE4xn). GCC works while MSVC give a clearer error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I found out from my colleagues. C++ is a pretty funny language. Mainly due to its long history.
The meaning of the compilation error is that the problematic line of code: h::test (h::TYPE::A);

The compiler parsed as "creating a variable of type h::test with the name h::TYPE::A". And then the compiler goes crazy, because you can't call variables that way.

All this is because someone once decided that it might be convenient to declare variables in this

```
int (value) style;
value = 42;
std::string (str);
str = "hello";
```

In other cases, the compiler parses the code correctly - it understands that this is a call to the constructor of the h::text class.